# How to build a neural network to extract specific information common to many PDFs with a different layout?

Tags: python, pdf

I am working on a Python project and I am trying to build a neural network model to extract specific information common across PDFs with different layouts. In simpler terms: for the time being, I have a total of 61 PDF forms with 61 different layouts which all have the common field 'Post Code'. The 'Post Code' field box is located in different page coordinates and I have to build and train a model which is able to load any of the PDFs and extract the Post Code field.

I can build a Python model which can extract the Post Code from only one PDF at a time, which means that if I had to iterate the process over 61 forms it would take too much time. I wouldn't have any problems if the PDFs were all with the same layout. I am struggling to find a way to make the process more efficient when it comes to PDFs with different layouts.

From what I have seen on Stack Overflow most problems are related to information extraction from one document or from more documents of the same layout. I would not want to branch out to another language other than Python and I would appreciate if anyone has found a way to perform specific information extraction from PDFs with different layouts.